# Match all <td> of a specific raw table with Webdriver Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm still new in web scraping and I have this question related to Webdriver.

Code Exemple :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> car </td>
            <td> bus </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td> car </td>
            <td> bus & train </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td> car </td>
            <td> bus & plane </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> food </td>
            <td> meat</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td> drink </td>
            <td> water </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the idea is that in my original code, I have multiple tables with the same ID and class names.

**Question** : How can i proceed to extract **all the TRs** that contains the word "**bus**".

I can't find the correct xpath syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a list of all the `<tr>` with their child `<td>` containing the text **bus** you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[.//td[contains(., 'bus')]]")
```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[.//td[contains(., 'bus')]]")))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use beautifulsoup

```
html = "<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> car </td>
            <td> bus </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td> car </td>
            <td> bus & train </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td> car </td>
            <td> bus & plane </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> food </td>
            <td> meat</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td> drink </td>
            <td> water </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

temp = soup.findAll("td") 

output = [x for x in temp if "bus" in x.text]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//td[contains(text(),'bus')]
```

you can use contains text , this gives all td that has bus in it