# How to get all href values of <a> in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, attributeerror, getattribute

Hi I am using selenium I want to find all values of hrefs present in webelement

```
links=profiles.find_elements_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute('href')
```

But it gives me error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting list of `a` tags so you can loop around and get your informations

```
a_list = profiles.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
all_links = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in a_list]
```

`all_links` will have list of urls you required

Answer (score 0):

[find_elements_by_tag_name(name)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_tag_name) would return a *list*. Where as [get_attribute(name)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) gets the given attribute or property of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). Hence the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

---

### Solution

You need to iterate through the elements and extract the value of the *href* attributes as follows:

```
print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in profiles.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")])
```

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [visibility_of_all_elements_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608635/match-all-td-of-a-specific-raw-table-with-webdriver-selenium-python/65609400#65609400) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(profiles, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a")))])
```